# Boolean returns false when it is clearly true

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a super simple multiplayer game for my app. And when the game the players play ends, the Boolean `gameFinished` becomes true. Most of the things that happen in the game first check to make sure `gameFinished` is equal to false, and that is where my problem comes in. After the game is finished, and my Boolean is clearly set to true, the Log returns `false` so the game keeps looping.

So here is the method that gets the results of the game

```
    private void getResults() {
    HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final String currentGameID) {
                games.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        HomePage.getUserPosition(new HomePage.CallbackPosition() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int position) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue().equals(false)) {
                                    if (position == 1) {
                                        if (youWin()) {
                                            getWinner(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), wager);
                                            Log.i("FlipCoin", dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue().toString());
                                        } else {
                                            getLoser(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), wager);

                                        }
                                    }
                                    endGame();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Sorry, there is a lot of sloppy code in that method.

But I have the line in there,
`if (dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue().equals(false)) {`

That checks to see if the game is finished, and if it is not finished then the winner or loser will be found at the end of the game.

However, once the game is over, and the winner and loser are found using this method, the method loops and continues to run over and over and over because it thinks that `gameFinished` is equal to `false`.

I have an `endGame()` method that happens at the end of this `getResults()` method

```
    private void endGame() { HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final String currentGameID) {
            games.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").setValue(true);
            games.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Log.i("FlipCoin", dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And in that method I clearly set `gameFinished` to true using this line
`games.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").setValue(true);`

And it is reflected in my realtime database that looks like this

[image]

So visually, it is true. And I also have a log statement in my endgame() method that returns `true`, so according to the log statement the Boolean should be true

But I also have log statements in my `getResults()` method, and that log returns false, even though the Boolean is clearly true

Can anyone help me with this odd problem?

This shows how the logcat is switching from false to true over and over which doesn't make any sense

[image]

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I set `gameFinished` to true at the end of the game. I only want the game to be running when `gameFinished` is equal to false, so that's why I check to make sure it is false.

Comment: Your code is very complex

Comment: @BrianHoang It's all super simple code. There's just kind of a lot of it with some variables mixed in. If you read my post everything should be clear, however if it is not please let me know so I can clarify.

Comment: I think what @BrianHoang is saying is that you have a lot of unnecessary code in there to get to the root of the issue.  It is kind of difficult to follow.  It would be worth trimming it down to only the bit that's not working the way you expect.  For example, how many times do you need to show us a call to `dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID)`, which returns the same thing every time?  What is the one thing you want to show that's unexpected?

Comment: @DougStevenson just trimmed it down substantially

Comment: And what is the value of `dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue()` if you log it?  Is it what you expect?  Have you stepped through in a debugger to examine it?  I'm not talking about the string value of it - the raw value.

Comment: Does the getValue returns Boolean or boolean? You might try to compare it to Boolean.False instead of just false

Comment: @Alex I have tried that and have the same result. The odd thing is the logs are different when I print the Boolean from different areas of the class

Comment: @DougStevenson when I get rid of the `toString()` they are still printing `false`  from the `getResults()` method and `true` from the `endGame()` method. This issue is very confusing for me

Comment: So you are expecting setValue() to finish immediately?  It's asynchronous - it does not finish immediately.

Comment: @DougStevenson The loop happens over and over again after `setValue()` is called. The value keeps switching from `false` to `true` even though it doesn't show this in the database and I never set the value to `false`. I posted a small picture of the logcat above to show what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a true value with a false. so it returns false. like this:

```
true.equals(false)
```

which returns false.

Change your code to this line of code:

```
if(dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue().equals(false))
```

to this:

```
if((Boolean)dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue())
```

Comment: have you logged the value of
dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue()

what is the value?

Comment: When it comes from the `endGame()` method, it returns true, and whenever it comes from the `getResults()` method it returns false. I don't know why once `endGame()` is called, it isn't seen as `true` from everywhere in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occur because of Boolean "gameFinished" is default initialized as false
You need to check getResults() method after your "gameFinished" set as true

Comment: If I set the `gameFinished` to true before I call my `getResults()`, then the `getResults()` won't work properly because it checks to make sure that `gameFinished` is equal to false before it does anything. Is there another way around this?

Comment: you can call your getResults() when "gameFinished" is false but you need to check it again when your "gameFinished" set true, and after thet you call your gameEnd(), you just need to manage your code, your logic is clear and good

Comment: I am testing some things out with this solution. I'll let you know if anything comes of it!